# Change Database in Sybase using Python

Tags: python, sybase, pymssql

I am connecting to Sybase using pymssql module in Python. I want count for all tables in each Database. I have list of all the Database present in that particular server, but how to switch between databases in Python.

When I am running - cursor.execute("USE " + db_name ) command in python it is throwing error:
pymssql.OperationalError: (5701, b"Changed database context to 'db_name'.\n")

Is there anyway other than connecting again and again using database = db_name in connection string?

Comment: `Msg 5701, Changed database context to 'db_name''` is not so much an error message as a general message that the `use db_name` command was **executed successfully**; see [this for reference](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00729.1500/html/errMessageAdvRes/CIHCDBFF.htm); at this point it looks like your python script **is** switching between Sybase databases successfully; to address this particular issue you'll need to configure the message/error handler to ignore this particular 'error'

Comment: Yes it seems it is throwing this error but database is getting updated. If I am handling the error, my code is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    cursor.execute("USE " + db_name)
    break
except pymssql.OperationalError:
    print('Move ahead')
```

Handling the error works. The Database is getting updated and code is working as expected.